# Does anyone know how to install ROS without a graphics card?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need everything except graphics dependent packages. How do I install ROS this way? More than just the bare bones but without graphics?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46260/does-anyone-know-how-to-install-ros-without-a-graphics-card?/) by [GraceC](https://answers.ros.org/users/3269/gracec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install individual ros stacks (or by package in new style groovy or later).  They will pull in all their required dependencies if you use apt to install them.

Also even if you don't have a graphics card you can still usually install the graphics libraries.  They just won't be very useful, and will require a little more disk space.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My recommendation would be to install `barebones` first then install specific packages that you need selectively, either by using `apt-get` or manually. The good thing about most of ROS stacks is their graphics-required packages are decoupled from the core packages. As a result, it is not that much important if you install stacks with graphical packages inside, on a computer not running X.

In our Pioneer robots, we usually install the `barebone` then add the driver and navigation stack without worrying about stacks being all non-graphical.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1